# Making one field/values equal to another field/values

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, fields-attributes, python-parser

I have created a new field called "SFX" in a shapefile called "myshape.shp":

```
input = r"C:\files\myshape.shp"
arcpy.AddField_management(input, "SFX", "TEXT", field_length=100)
```

There is now a field called "SFX" but there are no values in the cells. Now, in that same `shapefile`, I have another field called "SUFFIX".

```
fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(input)]
for field in fields:
    if field == 'SUFFIX':
        print field
>>>'SUFFIX'
```

Lets say 'SUFFIX' has values 'C', 'D', 'G', etc.... What I want to do, is for each row in 'SFX' I want that cell value to be equal to the corresponding cell value of 'SUFFIX'.

Without making complicated lists using a cursor, how would I do that using UpdateCursor or the Field Calculator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inserting the code shown below into your if statement should work.

```
# CalculateField_management (in_table, field, expression, {expression_type}, {code_block})
arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table="myshape.shp",
                                field="SFX",
                                expression="!SUFFIX!",
                                expression_type="PYTHON_9.3",
                                code_block="")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking how to calculate SFX field = SUFFIX field then:

```
import arcpy
shapefile = r'C:\shapefile.shp'
fields = ['SFX','SUFFIX']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shapefile, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0]=row[1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Examples like this can be found if you read the [help section of da.UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Right click your SUFFIX field, Field Calculator.

In the code block,

```
SFX = !SUFFIX!
```